# Sum of numpy array based on elements in another numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 arrays:

```
arr1 =np.array([10, 20, 15, 0, 45, 100])
arr2 =np.array([0,   3,  1, 6,  0,   0])
```

I want to get the sum of those elements from arr1 whose corresponding entries in arr2 are 0. The sum would be 10+45+100=155 in the example. How can I achieve this easily?

Comment: What is the issue with this one? `np.sum(arr1[arr2 == 0])`

Comment: Similar, but reads very nicely: `arr1.sum(where=arr2 == 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a boolean mask for `arr2` where the elements are equal to 0 and then use this mask to select the corresponding elements from `arr1`. Finally, you can calculate the sum of the selected elements.

```py
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([10, 20, 15, 0, 45, 100])
arr2 = np.array([0, 3, 1, 6, 0, 0])
mask = arr2 == 0  
result = np.sum(arr1[mask]) 
print(result)
```

**Output**:

```
155
```